# Path of folder in webapps in apache tomcat

Tags: java, struts2

how to find the path of folder,for example: Image present in webapps folder of Apache tomcat in my Java project.

Comment: I don't understand very well your question. Why do you want to access files inside your webapps folder? Your webapp should contain all the needed files inside the webapp and you can access all the files inside your webapp using the classpath.

If i'm not wrong, the only way that you can access files outside your webapp (that you shouldn't do) is using the standard File operations using absoulte file paths. And you'll only be able to access paths if the user that is running Tomcat has read permission.

Comment: Actually I am storing the images in Image folder created by me  inside webapps folder of apache tomcat.

Comment: And why you don't store the images inside the webapp? If the images are part of it, they should be inside. If the images are common to various webapps for example, or it is some kind of library with lots of files, then is good to have them outside, but in this case, they should go to some external storage (can be any disk folder) but not inside the webapps folder.

Comment: Finally, you can store the path to the images in a properties file, for example, and get it from there when you need to access to them. Yes, the same will work if you keep the folder inside the webapps folder, but this is not the place :)

Comment: Th problem is if I store the images in my project folder inside webapps then when i again deploy the war file there all the images will get deleted.So,where should i store the image.My question is similar to that if at time registration we want the user to upload the image/photo,then where would we store these images.

Comment: I guess that the images that you want to store are beign downloaded from somewhere right? In this case, you can create a folder in the filesystem of the server and store them there. Then, from your webapp code, you can access that folder using its absolute path. If you want to make it configurable, store the path in a properties file.

Answer (score 0):

To find path of your folder

Right click on your folder name --> select Properties --> select Resource on left side --> third option is Location.

That indicate the file location in your disk.